# vb.net cannot write Query to MSAccess file

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

i can access to local Access Database and i can add some data using Query, but it JUST shows its data when the program is alive. when I re-execute this program, i cannot see any previously added data and so do original Database file(SourceDB.mdb).

How can I save my data? Here is my code.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class UserForm
    Private myConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=.\SourceDB.mdb"
    Private mDbConn As OleDbConnection

    Private Sub Button_Search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Search.Click

        Dim myAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM user WHERE u_name = '" +    tBoxName.Text + "'", myConn)
        Dim myDataTable As New DataTable
        If tBoxName.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Input name")
        Else
            myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
            If myDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                tBoxPhone.Text = myDataTable.Rows(0).Item("u_phone")
                tBoxAddr.Text = myDataTable.Rows(0).Item("u_addr")
                tBoxBName.Text = myDataTable.Rows(0).Item("u_bname")
                tBoxBAccount.Text = myDataTable.Rows(0).Item("u_baccount")
                tBoxEtc.Text = myDataTable.Rows(0).Item("u_comment")
            Else
                MsgBox("No Name in Table")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_OK.Click
        Try
            If lblAOE.Text = "Add" Then
                Dim myAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("INSERT INTO user (u_name, u_phone, u_addr, u_bname, u_baccount, u_comment) VALUES ('" + _
                                                                       tBoxName.Text + "', '" + tBoxPhone.Text + "', '" + tBoxAddr.Text + "', '" + tBoxBName.Text + _
                                                                       "', '" + tBoxBAccount.Text + "', '" + tBoxEtc.Text + "')", myConn)
                Dim myDataTable As New DataTable
                myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
                Button_Add.Visible = True
                Button_Modify.Visible = True
                Button_OK.Visible = False
                ClearTextBoxes()
                Button_Clear.Text = "비우기"
            End If        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Delete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Delete.Click
        If MessageBox.Show("Sure Wanna delete data?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No Then
            MsgBox("Cancelled")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Dim myAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("DELETE FROM user WHERE u_name = '" + tBoxName.Text + "'", myConn)
            Dim myDataTable As New DataTable
            myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
            MsgBox("DELETED")
            ClearTextBoxes()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ClientForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.UserTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SourceDBDataSet.user)
        Me.Text = "User Form"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That's strange that this code works at all. USER is a reserved keyword for MS-Access. You cannot use as is but enclosed in square brackets `[USER]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `OleDbDataAdapter` trying to execute an INSERT operation (or a DELETE one), but this is not how the `OleDbDataAdapter` works.

An OleDbDataAdapter uses the SELECT command to retrieve the records and, if defined, its InsertCommand property to update records of a dataset through the call to the `OleDbDataAdapter.Update` method. You are not in this situation and you have your values directly in the textboxes. You could simply use an `OleDbCommand` with the appropriate sql statement (and this is the same for your DELETE method)

Try to change your code to

```
Dim cmdText = "INSERT INTO [user] (u_name, u_phone, u_addr, u_bname, " & _ 
              "u_baccount, u_comment) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)"
Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(cmdText, myConn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",tBoxName.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",tBoxPhone.Text )
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3",tBoxAddr.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4",tBoxBName.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5",tBoxBAccount.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6",tBoxEtc.Text )
cms.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I have changed your string concatenation to a more correct parameterized query to avoid Sql Injection and parsing problems in case one of your textbox values contains a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

you use OleDbCommand class. you make class object and  use ExecuteNonQuery for insert data
like

```
    Dim o As OleDbCommand
    o.Connection = con
    o.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    o.CommandText = "your Query"
    o.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

and you should use try block

try

o.ExecuteNonQuery()

catch

end try